# Broken promise, having trouble figuring it out (C++)

Tags: c++, concurrency, future

The error message I'm getting:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7712A9F2 in eye_tracking.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::future_error at memory location 0x010FEA50.
```

Code snippet of where I fork and join:

```
//CONCURRENCE
std::vector<costGrad*> threadGrads;
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::vector<std::future<costGrad*>> ftr(maxThreads);

for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)    //Creating threads
{
    int start = floor(xValsB.rows() / (double)maxThreads * i);
    int end = floor(xValsB.rows() / (double)maxThreads * (i+1));
    int length = end-start;
    std::promise<costGrad*> prms;
    ftr[i] = prms.get_future();
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() 
    {
        costThread(std::move(prms), params, xValsB.block(start, 0, length, xValsB.cols()), yVals.block(start, 0, length, yVals.cols()), lambda, m); 
    }));
}

for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)    //Collecting future
    threadGrads.push_back(ftr[i].get()); <-------I THINK THIS IS WHERE I'M MESSING UP

for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)    //Joining threads
    threads[i].join();
```

Following is the `costThread` function:

```
void costThread(std::promise<costGrad*> && pmrs, 
                const std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>& params, 
                const Eigen::MatrixXd& xValsB, 
                const Eigen::MatrixXd& yVals, 
                const double lambda, 
                const int m) 
{
    try
    {
        costGrad* temp = new costGrad;      //"Cost / Gradient" struct to be returned at end

        temp->forw = 0;
        temp->back = 0;

        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> matA;          //Contains the activation values including bias, first entry will be xVals
        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> matAb;         //Contains the activation values excluding bias, first entry will be xVals
        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> matZ;          //Contains the activation values prior to sigmoid
        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> paramTrunc;    //Contains the parameters exluding bias terms

        clock_t t1, t2, t3;
        t1 = clock();

        //FORWARD PROPAGATION PREP

        Eigen::MatrixXd xVals = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(xValsB.rows(), xValsB.cols() + 1, 1); //Add bias units onto xVal
        xVals.block(0, 1, xValsB.rows(), xValsB.cols()) = xValsB;

        matA.push_back(xVals);
        matAb.push_back(xValsB);

        //FORWARD PROPAGATION

        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
        {
            Eigen::MatrixXd paramTemp = params[i].block(0, 1, params[i].rows(), params[i].cols() - 1);      //Setting up paramTrunc

            paramTrunc.push_back(paramTemp);

            matZ.push_back(matA.back() * params[i].transpose());
            matAb.push_back(sigmoid(matZ.back()));


            Eigen::MatrixXd tempA = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(matAb.back().rows(), matAb.back().cols() + 1, 1); //Add bias units
            tempA.block(0, 1, matAb.back().rows(), matAb.back().cols()) = matAb.back();

            matA.push_back(tempA);
        }

        t2 = clock();

        //COST CALCULATION

        temp->J = (yVals.array()*(0 - log(matAb.back().array())) - (1 - yVals.array())*log(1 - matAb.back().array())).sum() / m;

        //BACK PROPAGATION

        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> del;
        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> grad;

        del.push_back(matAb.back() - yVals);

        for (int i = 0; i < params.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            del.push_back((del.back() * paramTrunc[paramTrunc.size() - 1 - i]).array() * sigmoidGrad(matZ[matZ.size() - 2 - i]).array());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
        {
            grad.push_back(del.back().transpose() * matA[i] / m);
            del.pop_back();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
        {
            int rws = grad[i].rows();
            int cls = grad[i].cols() - 1;
            Eigen::MatrixXd tmp = grad[i].block(0, 1, rws, cls);
            grad[i].block(0, 1, rws, cls) = tmp.array() + lambda / m*paramTrunc[i].array();
        }

        temp->grad = grad;

        t3 = clock();

        temp->forw = ((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000;
        temp->back = ((float)t3 - (float)t2) / 1000;

        pmrs.set_value(temp);
    }

    catch (...)
    {
        pmrs.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
    //return temp;
}
```

### EDIT:

Figured out the exception is a broken promise. I'm still having problems understanding what I'm getting wrong here. At the end of `costThread()` I use

```
pmrs.set_value(temp);
```

And I expect the following to get `temp`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)    //Collecting future
    threadGrads.push_back(ftr[i].get());
```

But somehow I'm getting it all wrong.

Comment: What does costThread() do? What is the result of what() on the exception? (If you add a catch in the loop that does the get() you should be able to inspect the exception)

Comment: The result of the exception is "broken promise". The costThread function is quite large, but I updated the original post and included it. At the end I use promise.set_value(...)

Comment: I guess that I could just use an async instead of promise at this point, but I would like to understand what I'm getting wrong here.

Comment: broken promise exceptions mean that you haven't called set_value on the promise before its destroyed.

Comment: How is it getting destroyed? The threads are joined in a loop following a loop that calls future.get(). My understanding was that the main thread would wait until it got the future, and the afterwards the threads would join.

Answer (score 5):

You have a race condition: you are passing a local variable to a thread by reference and moving it inside the thread; it will work only if a new thread manages to execute the move statement before local variable gets destructed due to going out of the scope. Normally, given the code, the destructor would be faster.

If you can use C++14, you can move the promise in the lambda initializer:

```
threads.push_back(
    std::thread([prms=std::move(prms)]() {
        costThread(prms, /* etc */);
    })
);
```

If you're limited to C++11, wrap the promise into a `std::shared_ptr` and pass it by value.

I would additionally handle exceptions in the worker threads and pass them to the processing thread through `std::promise::set_exception()`, though it's a matter of preference.